# Beginner SQL, Terminating fields loading csv. Terminating by comma

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, field, terminate

I am loading an excel csv into a MYSQL table but I do not know how to terminate the fields correctly as samples I have seen use commas to terminate.

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

But my issue seems to stem from the fact that I have VARCHAR values containing commas in some fields. eg. "sample **,** value"

how do I stop it from terminating on this comma or is there another way I can terminate fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can quote you string fields within `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the csv as a comma delimited csv from Excel it should put speech marks around anything with a comma "sample, value". It is the same with numbers eg 1,3434 becomes "1,3434" in the csv file. You need to add the line

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
```

This will take anything in speech marks as one column, rather than separating with the comma in between.